It is not possible to correctly add clickable markers to the Yandex.mapkit, android, java map
I created this method in different ways, which is presented below with all the code, it works somehow. I.e. it works, then it doesn't, as if it unloads handlers from memory or something else, I still can't figure it out. Or everything can work. I ask for help or any kind of hints, I can't already, I've been sitting for 5 days((
I tried to make a handler for the entire map, but I did not find such a thing at Yandex.
Here is the Fragment code:
package MainActivityFrag;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.example.traveldiary.R;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.yandex.mapkit.Animation;
import com.yandex.mapkit.MapKitFactory;
import com.yandex.mapkit.geometry.Point;
import com.yandex.mapkit.map.CameraPosition;
import com.yandex.mapkit.map.Map;
import com.yandex.mapkit.map.MapObject;
import com.yandex.mapkit.map.MapObjectTapListener;
import com.yandex.mapkit.map.PlacemarkMapObject;
import com.yandex.mapkit.mapview.MapView;
import com.yandex.runtime.image.ImageProvider;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import DataBase.Attraction;

public class MapFragment extends Fragment {
    String login;
    private static final int PERMISSION_ID = 44;
    MapView mapView;
    PlacemarkMapObject[] placemarks;
    double latitude, longitude;
    Attraction attraction = new Attraction(0, "Другое...",0.0,0.0,"null","null", 0);
    List<Attraction>attractions = new ArrayList<>();

    //Просто вывод карты на Экран с отображениием пользователя на данной карте
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        mapView = view.findViewById(R.id.mapview);

        attractions = attraction.getAttractions(getActivity());


        GettingСoordinates();

        loadAttractions();

        return view;
    }


    public Bitmap getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(Context context, int drawableId) {
        Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableId);
        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        } else if (drawable instanceof VectorDrawable) {
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                    drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
            drawable.draw(canvas);
            return bitmap;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("unsupported drawable type");
        }
    }

    public void GettingСoordinates(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    PERMISSION_ID);
        } else {
            FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());

            fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<android.location.Location>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();

                                // Создаем объект Point с координатами пользователя
                                Point userLocation = new Point(latitude, longitude);

                                // Получаем объект Map из MapView
                                Map map = mapView.getMap();

                                // Перемещаем камеру на позицию пользователя
                                map.move(new CameraPosition(userLocation, 14.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), new Animation(Animation.Type.SMOOTH, 0), null);

                                // Добавляем маркер на карту в позиции пользователя
                                PlacemarkMapObject placemark = map.getMapObjects().addPlacemark(userLocation);
                                placemark.setOpacity(0.5f);

                                // Преобразуем VectorDrawable в Bitmap
                                Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.human);

                                // Устанавливаем иконку маркера
                                placemark.setIcon(ImageProvider.fromBitmap(bitmap));
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }





    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStart();
        mapView.onStart();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        mapView.onStop();
        MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStop();
        super.onStop();
    }





    @SuppressLint("Range")
    public void loadAttractions() {

        for (Attraction attraction : attractions) {

            // Создаем объект Point с координатами достопримечательности
            Point attractionLocation = new Point(attraction.Longitude, attraction.Latitude);

            // Получаем объект Map из MapView
            Map map = mapView.getMap();

            // Добавляем маркер на карту в позиции достопримечательности
            PlacemarkMapObject placemark = map.getMapObjects().addPlacemark(attractionLocation);
            placemark.setOpacity(0.5f);

            // Преобразуем VectorDrawable в Bitmap
            Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.marker);

            // Устанавливаем иконку маркера
            placemark.setIcon(ImageProvider.fromBitmap(bitmap));

            // Устанавливаем имя и описание маркера
            placemark.setUserData(new Object[]{attraction.Name, attraction.Description});

            // Устанавливаем слушатель нажатия на объект карты
            placemark.addTapListener(new MapObjectTapListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMapObjectTap(@NonNull MapObject mapObject, @NonNull Point point) {
                    Object[] userData = (Object[]) mapObject.getUserData();
                    String name = (String) userData[0];
                    String description = (String) userData[1];

                    new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                            .setTitle(name)
                            .setMessage(description)
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    // Закрываем диалоговое окно
                                }
                            })
                            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                            .show();

                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
    //-----------------------------------
}

